# Typescript: can't extract value type of object with labeled type guard

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I don't know why object value type can't be extracted properly with generic as below.
Could you tell me why it doesn't work if you know?

```
export type ValueType = {
    type: "string",
    value: string,
} | {
    type: "number",
    value: number,
}

/** 1. Extract value type of "string" type */
type StringValueType = (ValueType & {type: "string"})["value"];
// type StringValueType = string

/** 2. Extract value type of each type by generic */
type ValueTypeWithGeneric<T extends ValueType["type"]> = (ValueType & {type: T})["value"];
type StringValueTypeWithGeneric = ValueTypeWithGeneric<"string">;
// type StringValueTypeWithGeneric = string | number
// I expect this type to be string
```

Comment: Wow, I can see exactly why this happens but I haven't found a source saying this is a bug/working as intended/a design limitation. TypeScript will eagerly reduce `({ a: 0, b: "x" } & { a: T })["b"]` to `"x"` no matter what `T` is, even though if `T` is something like `1`, it "should" be `never`.  If you want to work around this I'd use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) like [this](//tsplay.dev/WJq06m).  Do you want me to write that answer up or are you looking for an *authoritative* answer for why it doesn't work?

Comment: Okay, [microsoft/TypeScript#45428](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45428) is the authoritative answer; it's a design limitation.  Shall I write up an answer or am I missing something about your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understood it's a design limitation and can solve the problem by using `Extract<T, U>` . You suggested me a complete answer. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design limitation in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#45428](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45428) for an authoritative answer.  When faced with a type of the following form

```
type X<T> = ({ a: 0, b: "x" } & { a: T })["b"]
```

the compiler presumes that this will always be equivalent to

```
type X<T> = ({ a: 0 & T, b: "x" })["b"]
```

no matter what the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` will be.  And therefore the compiler reduces this eagerly to

```
type X<T> = "x"
```

So `X<T>` is just `"x"` independently of `T`:

```
type XT0 = X<0> // "x" 
type XT1 = X<1> // "x"
```

But when you actually do this with a non-generic type in place of `T`, you see different behavior:

```
type X0 = ({ a: 0, b: "x" } & { a: 0 })["b"] // "x"
type X1 = ({ a: 0, b: "x" } & { a: 1 })["b"] // never
```

It is the discrepancy between `X<1>` and `X1` which you have run into.

---

In TypeScript 3.8 and below, there *was* no discrepancy.  Type `X1` would evaluate to `"x"` also:

```
// TS3.8 and below
type X1 = ({ a: 0, b: "x" } & { a: 1 })["b"] // "x" in TS3.8-
```

Even though it's not possible to have a value with an `a` property of both type `"0"` and type `"1"`, the compiler kept `{a: 0, b: "x"} & {a: 1}` as-is, and therefore the `b` property is seen to be of type `"x"`.

But TypeScript 3.9 introduced support for [reducing intersections by discriminant properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36696).  Now the compiler sees `{a: 0, b: "x"} & {a: 1}` as [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), and thus the `b` property is also of the `never` type.

And that's great.  But unfortunately the behavior in the face of generics was not updated to account for this change.  When intersecting with generic `{a: T}`, no reduction takes place, no matter what.  Oh well. It's a design limitation.

---

The recommended workaround here is to avoid using intersections for this purpose, and instead use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) whose intent is to filter a union type `T` to just those members assignable to `U`.  So instead of `{a: 0, b: "x"} & {a: T}`, you can write `Extract<{a: 0, b: "x"}, {a: T}>` and get consistent behavior:

```
type Ex<T> = Extract<{ a: 0, b: "x" }, { a: T }>["b"] 
type Ex0 = Ex<0> // "x" 
type Ex1 = Ex<1> // never
```

And that means your example will start behaving as desired as well:

```
/** 1. Extract value type of "string" type */
type StringValueType = Extract<ValueType, { type: "string" }>["value"];
// type StringValueType = string 

/** 2. Extract value type of each type by generic */
type ValueTypeWithGeneric<T extends ValueType["type"]> = Extract<ValueType, { type: T }>["value"];
type StringValueTypeWithGeneric = ValueTypeWithGeneric<"string">;
// type StringValueTypeWithGeneric = string
```

[Playground link to code in TS4.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/LAKALgngDgpgBADQAxwLxwBQG84EMBccSANHAEaEBEAHpXAL5wBkcOBRDAlANqVmUBdOAHphcGnUC8G4Fkd0JFiIAjGkxtCJclVoNmrPIWX0efQSLEA7GADcYAJzgzQc6PAQAeACoA+Fdn1FSCnFtRhY1OA8uXn4hUWDKUDj5V08fdAlnBQQPFHR3JB84iQdZcBdED2U8t0VCsWLJQDkdpzKFAFFqVJUOsFtcAGMwN3CNIOL6UnDI+i9owUz4Dty4DrcCs3iFleoq7Zq6uEsbWxbQGGooAHtbMDhkuAA1XAAbAFcYD3L0LFA4P7uXFQAM69ACW5gA5pRiL9-lYXu9CCDbOCITCQIwAD6sWF-ZJUcyvAC2ZDs0NxcHhbxghEJJLs6PoLWEACoWXBFAA6ba9Aa3KnvAEKS4AM3EyNRdHuLOEWwAymDIU9qZ8FOgen1Bm5le9VTBJkKaeLFVCGLNKAKYIIANyJMT3BUopUIj5fOASyHMtlwABM3I1fMpLsNcFFcBgAwAFiGyBA4BCYJYUf04DKtjrXbAAOqgsCRgDiibsoP6nnD1DAiYAJkDHi69bxkoI0jzNUMM3qDfiImbeJabfKTR2XDm84WkyWVMPs7mC0Xk25KB6oV5bSAkuVHajpzBR3OJyn0MvQEA)

[Playground link to code in TS3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=3.8.3#code/LAKALgngDgpgBADQAxwLxwBQG84EMBccSANHAEaEBEAHpXAL5wBkcOBRDAlANqVmUBdOAHphcGnUC8G4Fkd0JFiIAjGkxtCJclVoNmrPIWX0efQSLES4kwHI7oOdHgIAPABUAfCuz6ipCuO2MWNThnLl5+IVE-SlBI+QcXd3QJOwUEZxR0JyR3SIsZFIdnZUzHRRzzbWtbcHs4AFFqBJUGsAAnXABjMEcgjV8LelIgkPpXMMEC+uoMqcdssyjJhuLZsoWAOxgANxhW6tAYaigAe1awODi4ADVcABsAVxhnWvQsUDgPi-sqAGc2gEt1gBzSjEd6fLZ3R6EP6tQFAsEgRgAH1Y4I+cSo63uAFsyLtQei4JCHjBCNi8btEfRqsIAFR0uCKAB0UzanXOJMeXwUxwAZuJYfC6Jc6cJJgBlAHAm6k54KdAtdpdRyyx7ymBDHlkwXSkEMMaULkwQQAbhiYkuUrhMqhTxecCFwNpDLgACZWUqOcS7dq4Py4DBOgALP1kCBwIEwTZwjpwMWTNX22AAdX+YGDAHFo7t-h0XIHqGBowATH7XO0a3hxQSJNnK7pJjVazHBA28Y1myV6pv2NMZ7MxvMqXup9NZnOxxyUJ0g1zmkCxWrW+GjmD9idDuPoWegIA)